# Gatekeeper OPA AssignMetadata dynamically from userInfo of current user

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent

I would like to assign metadata (annotations) to any resource created/updated with the username who creates/updates that resource. In kyverno, it's straightforward. But for some reasons, we stop using Kyverno. And we want to use OPA.

Fortunately, we found that OPA supports the metadata assignment/mutation using AssignMetadata CR.
But in the official documentation/samples, it assign the value STATICALLY "admin"

```yaml
apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1
kind: AssignMetadata
metadata:
  name: demo-annotation-owner
spec:
  match:
    scope: Namespaced
  location: "metadata.annotations.owner"
  parameters:
    assign:
      value: "admin" ## <-- static :(
```

Is there a way to set that value dynamically from the current user info ?

Some how , something like following:

```yaml
  parameters:
    assign:
      value: "{{ req.AdmissionRequest.UserInfo.Username }}"
```